# Gitlab Pipeline: `Improper Input Validation`

Tags: python, validation, security, pip, requirements.txt

In GitLab, I've been trying to scan for vulnerable dependencies and found the follow vulnerability issue with `pip`:

[image: improperInputValidation]

Does anyone know if there's a work around for this error popping up? I don't use `--extra-index-url` anywhere in my project.

Thank you!

Comment: You didn't show us your project config files. At least one of them is `requirements.txt`.